# Niner Biocnetric Compatibility

Tags: bottom-bracket

Have an older Niner Air 9 Carbon that has the original Biocentric eccentric hub.
Does anyone know if the Biocentric II is compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped by the local Niner shop and they told me the II is compatible